# Rails - jQuery click event not playing nicely

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a jQuery script that works outside of Rails, but does not work in Rails (v4.0.2). I came across some posts related to Turbolinks - which mention page reload - but I have yet to find a solution.

In the code snippet below, `$('body').toggleClass('push-to-right');`
works in Rails, but the click event only fires for `$('document')`. I want to use a button  `$('#parent')` which is a direct parent of `slideButton`.

```
var slideMenu = $('.slide-menu'),
    slideButton = $('.slide-button');

$('#parent').on('click', slideButton, function (e) {
    slideButton.toggleClass('active');
    $('body').toggleClass('push-to-right');
    slideMenu.toggleClass('open');
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/sVdtd/3/)

Has anyone had similar issues before?

Comment: I humbly suggest your problem has nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: Your Fiddle works fine for me - Chrome 35.0

Comment: It works fine in a normal html setup as I mentioned in the question but not only partially working in Rails.

Comment: I updated your question.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks if using_rails_4? ;)

Comment: what does the html where it doesn't work look like?

Comment: @user3334690 Hi, it obviously doesn't work by looking at the rendered page and I also tested it through inspect element and those problem areas don't add/toggle selectors when event is fired in rails setup.

Comment: yes, but since I can't think of why it would behave the way you are describing off the top of my head... I thought it would help to see the code that doesn't work... in order to see if anything jumps out...

Comment: @Upperstage Thanks for updating my question. So much clearer!

Comment: I'm on rails 4.1 and getting the same issue. If do this from the browser js console it works: $("h3").click(function() { return alert("Clicked that thang");}); but the same thing in my rails apps js is not triggering.

Comment: @SeongLee did you have any luck resolving this? Please share it as an answer if so, and help those of us following your footsteps.